# Why does the Night King look different than his cave paintings depiction?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season 7 episode 4 *The Spoils of War* we see Daenerys and Jon looking at cave paintings believed to depict the Children of the Forest, the First Men and the White Walkers.

In the image of the White Walkers we're shown what is meant to be the Night King but he looks different. In the cave picture he seems to have a beard as opposed to the 'clean shaven' look we know him to have.

Is there any purpose behind this or has 8000 years brought on a change of image?

[image: left:cave image right:Night King]

Comment: "*As for the Night's King (the form I prefer), in the books he is a legendary figure, akin to Lann the Clever and Brandon the Builder, and no more likely to have survived to the present day than they have".*; https://grrm.livejournal.com/428790.html?thread=21723638#t21723638

Comment: @Valorum I assumed that the Night King and Night's King were separate with the former exclusive to the TV show with the scene in the question not guaranteed to be in the books?

Comment: You'd have to ask Martin to clarify, but he seems to be saying that the Night King (seen in the show)  isn't 8000 years old, nor the original.

Comment: Thanks for the link. To me it implies there is/was more than one Night King and the show ran out of time......

Comment: Because the CGI wasn't as good 8000 years ago, lower quality image to paint off.

Comment: Clearly, the one in the cave painting was from the mirror universe.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that White Walkers don't grow facial hair just like regular people? They definitely age - some are turned as infants, and obviously don't stay infants.

Comment: Why can't The Night King shave?

Comment: This question was supposed to be about the possibility of more than one Night King not is he no longer a hipster. Then Night King was a clean shaven man when turned and there is no evidence that Wights grow facial hair, a white walker decomposing is no the same as growing.

Comment: It's possible that the children of the forest did their ritual multiple times, and this is one of the night-king-like monsters further south that these were fighting with the dragonglass they mined in Draginstone (and they killed this one, but not the one far north). I don't think we've really got anything to go on though.

Comment: No, the show makes it clear the Night King is the original Night King and there is only one, and he wanted to extinguish all living creatures and that's it. No additional Night Kings, no other driving force for the White Walkers. What GRRM is saying is that *his* Night's King and the TV show's Night King (note the different spellings) are *not* the same character. This is one point where the books and the TV show diverge.

Answer (score 6):

This won't be a conclusive answer, but...

...I don't see a huge contradiction that can't be explained away. Cave paintings in real life are not exactly equal to the subjects they portray:

[image: Neanderthal cave painting]

Even within the context of this TV show, the paintings done by the Children of the Forest are not particularly realistic (I think Neanderthals actually had better artistic skills!):

[image: Children of the Forest cave painting]

As for the picture of the Night King, if you squint your eyes it kinda looks like him; all major features are there. If you squint your eyes even harder, the "beard" *could* be conflated with the thingy around his neck. With some artistic license, sure, but it doesn't seem like an outrageous mistake to me.

As an aside, note that the "humans" in the Children of the Forest drawing don't look like real humans either, but this can't be called a "mistake" or continuity error; it's just that the Children weren't going for a realistic arts style, just for a non-realistic but figurative one. Or maybe they just weren't very good artists ;)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not going to accept this answer because there is a big difference between stylised (top image) and creation of a feature (beard). Also the top image looks like someone riding a camel using a harness and looks more modern and African than Neanderthal?

Comment: @Seamusthedog I may be wrong but I think those comes from (Tassili n'Ajjer)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tassili_n%27Ajjer], more than 12.000 years old prehistoric cave art. It's african(In today's Algeria), and it's not Neanderthal (but rather Homo Sapiens), but it's still prehistoric

Comment: @Seamusthedog What difference does it make whether it's Neanderthal? It's *older* than the drawing of the Children of the Forest (in their fictional timeline). It's more abstract, too.

Comment: @Kepotx Thanks! I got confused because [this article](https://www.salon.com/2018/12/16/the-worlds-oldest-cave-paintings-were-probably-made-by-neanderthals_partner/) used it as a stock image to discuss Neanderthal paintings. In any case, the point of my answer still stands :)

Comment: @AndresF. the second sentence in my comment is a question not a statement.

Comment: @Kepotx same as comment to Andres F. I'm only asking a question.

Comment: @Seamusthedog Hmm, whether Neanderthal or not, the painting seems to be prehistoric. But any cave painting would have served: they are never *accurate*. The men and animals don't look like real animals, they are like abstracted representations of them :) For this reason, it's not totally unreasonable to believe the child-like Children could have drawn the neck ornament as a beard. Or maybe they represent "age" with a beard, even though the actual NK didn't sport one. All I'm saying is that it doesn't seem like a major continuity error to me, because it can easily be explained away :)

Comment: @AndresF. this is dragging on and I don't think I'm being understood. I never said the image you provided wasn't ancient just more modern than Neanderthal. Re: NK image, I never said it was a continuity error or implied that. Is there an in universe reason for it, 2 NKs etc.

Comment: @Seamusthedog I know you just asked, and I answered "it doesn't matter whether it's Neanderthal, because it's a prehistoric cave painting taken from an article about prehistoric cave paintings. For my example, any cave painting would have served". And to your second question: "no, there aren't two Night Kings. It's just one Night King. In-universe, it can be explained by this (my answer followed)." I know you were just asking questions, I hope I've answered them :)